# Save data to a user session

Tags: asp.net

i am working on a online forum like where anybody whether registered or un-registered user can comment on a particular topic/article etc...

so, when the user (registered/un-registered) leave their comments we have a process for approving by admin which is behind the scene....

so my question is, when the user leave their comments then i want to hold on to their comments till their comments approved by admin or till the session is alive

the same user can leave one comment or many comments to a topic/article...
on the same page i will have different comments leave by other users which are approved by admin...

i would like to know what is the best way to handle?

example:

```
[some topic here.........................
 ...................................................]

*comments:*

abc ............................... [pendign approval] //this data will be coming from session

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx......................[approved] //all the approved coming from db

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..................[approved]
............
..................
.................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should depend session for this. You should probably store the comment status with a different status in the table.

Ex : When a comment is newly posted ,save it to the database with status as 0 / "Pending"

Wen Admin approves, change it to 1/"Approved"

If admin rejects , change it to -1/ "rejected" / delete the record if you dont want to store it any more

When the page loads (for all users/public), get the records filtered by status

```
SELECT ID,COMMENT FROM COMMENTS WHERE STATUS=1 AND POST_ID=@postId
```

When the page loads (for all a user who posted the comment), get the records filtered by status ( include pending also now)

```
SELECT ID,COMMENT FROM COMMENTS WHERE 
 ((STATUS IN =1)
 OR (STATUS =0  AND CREATED_BY=@currentUserId)) 
 AND POST_ID=@postId
```

Comment: so here is the question i have: i am displaying the only comments that approved by admins so for the pending it should be displayed for that session only...

Comment: @AbuHamzah what if the customer closes the browser and logged back in  ?

Comment: in that case that user consider as a new user/visitor, and can again post the comments and again it will be pending waiting for approval....hope i answer you question

Comment: Yea. You may use session approach for those unregistered usres. Use database approach for registered usres. Keep in mind that having so much items in session is not a good idea as session will be stored in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allocate anonymous users an account automatically (similar to the registered users ones). When a user registers you can upgrade their account. In this way the same process can be used to display comments from both.